# Laravel throwing error on create method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$permission = new Permission();
$permPost = $permission->create([ 
    'name'        => 'post',
    'slug'        => [          // pass an array of permissions.
        'create'     => true,
        'view'       => true,
        'update'     => true,
        'delete'     => true
    ],
    'description' => 'manage post permissions'
]);
```

throwing error on passing array within array on create method laravel 5.4 :

> Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into permissions (name, slug, description, updated_at, created_at) values (post, 1, manage post permissions, 2017-04-27 05:32:41, 2017-04-27 05:32:41))

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: What is the error? check your log file and post here. /storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `permissions` (`name`, `slug`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (post, 1, manage post permissions, 2017-04-27 05:32:41, 2017-04-27 05:32:41))

Comment: You'll need to serialize the slug data to store them in a DB cell...

Comment: create function has array within array, so how come first array is being passed correctly?

Comment: Because `name` (and other items) matches with a SQL column. But `create`, `view`, `update` and `delete` has to be stored in one cell and it's not possible to store an array in a SQL cell. Use json or php serialize.

Comment: Yeah this sounds logical. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel allows [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) mutator:

*Just update your Permission model to have:*

```
protected $casts = [
    'slug' => 'array',
];
```

**From the docs:**

> Once the cast is defined, you may access the options attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from JSON into a PHP array. When you set the value of the options attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage

So, now you no need to encode manually, Laravel does everything for you automatically! *Just pass array as an array.*

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try json_encode on `slug` field, then pass it to the Eloquent to persist in DB:

```
'slug' => json_encode([
   'create' => true,
   'view'   => true,
   'update' => true,
   'delete' => true
)]
```

Comment: yes i know it can work, but my question is why first array is passing correctly.

Comment: Laravel out of the box will cast the array into the Eloquent model, but it does not support multi-dimensional arrays, because you are using a RDBMS database, not a NoSql one, unless you use a mutator in your model

Answer (score 0):

Slug is a string in the database. You passing an array to it.

You could store it as JSON or Serialise it, but this is a database design smell. You should think about what other tables you need to store this data properly, depending on how it will be used elsewhere in you application.